# Rearrange Rows in Microsoft Excel to Columns in new sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have a list of data that I need to rearrange in a specific way in the next sheet.

[image: the sets of data]

I want to make the data to automatically be inputted to the next sheet as below as the total data is actually a lot and it takes time to do this by transposing and copy pasting to the correct order.

[image: the intended result]

Is it possible to make the data be arranged as such automatically by functions/macros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve it with a pivot table:

1. select a cell in your data, go to insert - pivot table, click ok
2. add all columns as column headers
3. select all data in your pivot table and CTRL+C (copy)
4. paste special - values and number formatting to a new location

Note: adding empty line between records didn't work for me through pivot table settings, but you can always add an empty column to your source data and include it in the pivot table too.

[image]

Comment: But is it possible to separate it by having to add 2 cells after each 'sets' of data?

Comment: yes, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want the data on the next sheet formatted. To match the diagrams I assumed A2->A2,B2->A3, etc until A3 ->A13
Step 1 assign "Spot" as a name to A1 in the source sheet. ($a$1 could be used if did not want to use names)

Step 2 offset to step through data using a name of Val

- Val=OFFSET(Spot,1+INT((ROW()-2)/10),MOD(ROW()-2,10))

Step 3, use a test to differs from a blank cell and a 0 in orginal data

- =If(Val="","",Val)

Alternative and explanation

- RW=1+INT((ROW()-2)/10)
  this figures out the row component of an offset. the 10 = how wide the data is. If there were more (or less) columns then the 10 would need to be modified. The -2 is for starting the output in the second row. This could be adjusted if that is needed. The goal is to make the first row() to = zero.
- CW=MOD(ROW()-2,10)
  This figures out the column component offset.  The math is similar to the row's math in that 10 is how wide, and -2 is for first row. Mod returns the remainder after dividing (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2...)

Using these names, Val becomes

- Val=offset(spot,rw,cw)

Spot and RW, CW could be adjusted as needed depending on where you start the data and how many columns.  If the output zone becomes 2 columns wide, then their would be a minor adjustment to RW and CW for including +column()-1 and changing width to 5 instead of 10

Comment: I kind of understand your method and calculation, but where do I input the 'formulas' in?

Comment: The name manager is on the formula tab in the ribbon, or using a keybd shortcut of Alt-I-N-D, this assumes an excel later than 2003

Comment: If you have not used it before, first select a cell on the second row and either use the keyboard shortcut or click on the name manager on the ribbon.  Put RW and CW in a group of cells to verify that the values or as expected. Then place inside offset formula and verify get correct answers as a range. Then make Val and replace some of the offset formula wih =Val and verify no change.